# jQuery onClick passing $(this) to ajax call

Tags: jquery

I tried every way and can't seem to get this right. Onclick, I want to take $(this) and pass it to my ajax call so that when it's done calling, I could take further action on $(this).

Here's my code:

```
  $('.but_deleteMaterial').on('click',function(e){
    e.preventDefault();

    var r = $(this);

    $.get('/scripts/delete_material.asp?action=delete&cID='+cID,function(r){
      r.closest('.row').hide(); // hide the row that was deleted.
    });

  });
```

Comment: Just remove the `r` from the handler function parameters and your code works fine: https://jsfiddle.net/RoryMcCrossan/8uwyqqon/. The problem was simply that the `r` you passed in hid the original `r` in the outer scope

Answer (score 2):

You're overriding your variable `r` with the function parameter you're passing in the callback of the `$.get`-function.

Correct would be:

```
$.get('/scripts/delete_material.asp?action=delete&cID='+cID,function(data){
      r.closest('.row').hide(); // hide the row that was deleted.
});
```

`data` (in this case) or the function-parameter in the callback (in general) contains the data which is returned (echoed) in your server-side script.

Answer (score 0):

If you want r to contain DOM elem that that was clicked.

```
var r = event.target;
```

In order to hide row based on call try using ajaxStop or ajaxComplete

```
    $(document).ajaxComplete(function(event, xhr, settings) {
    if (settings.url === "...") {
        /* Put your code here */
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [bind](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) method to set the `this` object to your jQuery this object. Works ie9+ only.

```
$('.but_deleteMaterial').on('click',function(e){
e.preventDefault();

$.get('/scripts/delete_material.asp?action=delete&cID='+cID,function(){
  this.closest('.row').hide(); // hide the row that was deleted.
}.bind($(this)));
```

});